# Get Duplicate field Name in single list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

I have a `List<Car> lstcar` with properties

```
name-Zen id-1211 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-Alto id-1521 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-Nano id-9911 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-800 id-1721 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-zen id-711 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-Swift id-9911 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-Nano id-1081 MfYear-1990 Color-black
```

I want name of repeated items based on name
eg: I want "Zen , Nano", but when I do

```
   List<Car> dup = lstcar.GroupBy(s => s.CarName)
         .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())
         .OrderBy(s => s.CarName)
         .ToList<Car>();
```

I get `dup` has this value

```
name-Zen id-1211 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-Alto id-1521 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-Nano id-9911 MfYear-1990 Color-black
name-800 id-1721 MfYear-1990 Color-black     
name-Swift id-9911 MfYear-1990 Color-black
```

but I want

```
 name-Zen id-1211 MfYear-1990 Color-black     
 name-Nano id-9911 MfYear-1990 Color-black    
 name-zen id-711 MfYear-1990 Color-black   
 name-Nano id-1081 MfYear-1990 Color-black
```

How do I get duplicates from one `List<T>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `Where` clause to get only groups with more then 1 element and `SelectMany` to flatten results into one list:

```
var duplications = lstcar.GroupBy(s => s.CarName)
                         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                         .SelectMany(g => g)
                         .ToList();
```

I see you won't *Zen* and *zen* in the same group, so you should change your `GroupBy` to: `GroupBy(s => s.CarName.ToLower())`